# Django RedirectView with a URL containing url-escaped characters

Tags: python, django, url

I have a RedirectView in Django that reads from the database the URL to redirect to.
I don't control which URL is given except that it is indeed a valid URL.

The problem occurs when the URL that is kept in the database has this form:

http://www.example.com/example?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

as you may notice the URL contains "quoting" to `%3A%2F%2F` that stands for `://` .

The problem is that after setting the `self.url` to this value the RedirectView performs its `dispatch` method and throws an exception on this line:

`url = self.url % kwargs`

the Exception thrown is:

`ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 39`

I assume this happens because python tries to format the url as string and has trouble dealing with the `%`. But I'm not sure..

now, the `kwargs` dict is empty and what seems to fix the problem is "unquoting" the url before the dispatch is performed using `urllib`'s `unquote` method that translates the `%3A%2F%2F` back to `://` in the string.

This fixes the problem, but I wonder if there's a more "pythonic" way to deal with that and if this is indeed what is causing the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is what is causing your problem. Your solution seems fine to me

Answer (score 0):

Instead of de-urlencoding the string, I suggest escaping the `%` as `%%` in order to work with `printf`-like string formatting, which is cleaner in my opinion. But this can become tricky if you need to support parameters in your base URL. You'll need to extract them one by one and check whether it's an URL-encoded char or a `%`-format parameter.